# Why cannot use Ctrl+A in my input?

Tags: javascript, html

When i fill some data like "abcdefg" in input , why i can not use select all function ( ctrl + a ) , How can i do ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery.fn.placehold = function(place) {
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    var placeholder =  'placeholder' in i;

    if(placeholder) {
        this.attr("placeholder", place);
    } else {
        this.val(place);
        this.css({color: '#ccc'});
    }

    this.blur(function() {
        var e = $(this);
        if(e.val()=="" && !placeholder) {
            e.val(place);
            e.css({color: "#ccc"});
        }
    }).bind("focus focusin click mousedown", function() {
        var e = $(this);
        if(e.val()==place && !placeholder) {
            e.css({color: 'black'});
            e.val("");
        }
    }).bind("keydown keypress keyup change", function() {
        var e = $(this);
        e.val(e.val());
    });


};

$(function() {
    $('#text_placehold').placehold("Start Searching");
});
});//]]>  

</script>



<input spellcheck="false" id="text_placehold" type="text">
```

Comment: [Using the same Javascript and HTML works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/c9pvR/). Try tweaking the code in the link until you can reproduce your error, fork it, then post a link so we can see the bad behaviour.

Comment: Can reproduce at http://jsbin.com/EwEnEqoso . The `e.val(e.val())` is forcing an update on the textfields value and thus disables the selection which Cmd/Ctrl-A invokes.